# kerberos authentication for mongodb in node running on windows without specifying password?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, kerberos

It it possible to use kerberos authentication with mongodb without specifying password when running the node app in windows environment?

I can successfully log in to my mongo server from command line:

`mongo.exe --host xxxx.yyyy.zzzz.com --port 27017 --username FLast@YYYY.ZZZZ.COM --authenticationMechanism=GSSAPI --authenticationDatabase=$external`

But I can't do the same thing in the code:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const f = require('util').format;
const assert = require('assert');

const server = 'xxxx.yyyy.zzzz.com';
const principal = 'FLast@YYYY.ZZZZ.COM';
const urlEncodedPrincipal = encodeURIComponent(principal);

// Let's write the actual connection code
MongoClient.connect(f("mongodb://%s@%s/?authMechanism=GSSAPI&gssapiServiceName=mongodb", urlEncodedPrincipal, server), function (err, client) {
  assert.equal(null, err);

  client.close();
});
```

I get back an error: `AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: null == 'Error: SEC_E_LOGON_DENIED The logon failed.'`

What caught my eye is that 10Gen's own tests all specify password when running in windows environment (see second half of https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/test/functional/kerberos_tests.js)

So is it possible to authenticate without providing the password when running in windows?

Comment: Disagree. The server is configured correctly. The question is about proper driver configuration in the code. Think "what's the correct connection string format for..." type of question. It belongs here.

Comment: Sorry, must have been posted in between a couple of off-topic questions and it just got the standard message. This can be a difficult one to test since it's an Enterprise feature only. I'm also not sure it's supported on Windows, but I'm thinking more that it's not. Might look into it on the weekend if the question is still unanswered.

Comment: @AlexPolkhovsky did you figure this out?